# Is it faster to swap an img src or show/hide multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, frontend

What is the best practice to use when swapping an image on a webpage? Altering the image source or just showing/hiding multiple images on the page?

Comment: It's faster to use a CSS sprite and shift the background position

Comment: This would be for a large image rather than a sprite. Good point to keep in mind however.

Comment: browser caching makes this question moot.

Comment: Good question, helped me to get a solution to a problem I was having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to choose in order to balance speed, with your two options:

> Altering the image source

this way, the page will load faster because it only gets the visible images but it will take a little longer to show the new image when you change src attribute

> just showing/hiding multiple images

this way, you are loading all the images on page load which will make it slower on loading and faster on swapping the images

Comment: Good points thank you. I feel the initial page load is more important than elements loading on the page, so I guess the source swapping wins for me.

Comment: You can programmatically pre-load the images still, so at 'swap-time', you've still got them available on-demand without waiting for the network. Example: http://perishablepress.com/preloading-images-with-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

At the load time, multiple images will slow down the webpage, but at the execution time, I think it will be fastest to show/hide the images