# Optimal way of showing/hiding images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I read this question here ["Is it faster to swap an img src or show/hide multiple images?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938062/is-it-faster-to-swap-an-img-src-or-show-hide-multiple-images)

The answer to the question has two options.

1) Alter the image source - Page loads faster, swapping consumes time.

2) Pre load images and then simply show/hide - Page loads a little slower, swapping is quicker

To my problem, I go with the second option as load time is 2nd priority for me. But is there best or most optimal way of writing the code?

Let's say I keep getting numbers (10,11,15,25,13,19 etc randomly) from somewhere. I have to show that many images (small dots, 30 in number, each image about 1kb).. I also have the condition, every dot represents 1.5. So I have written the following code.

```
var dots = new Array(30);

function onBodyLoad() {
    for(var j=0;j<30;j++)
        dots[j] = document.getElementById("dotimg"+j);
}

//called by some method every second.
//argument: the value received from somewhere.

function updateImages(s) {
    var x = Math.round(s);
    var dotPos = x/1.5;
    for(var i=0;i<dotPos;i++) {
        dots[i].style.visibility='visible'; //show that many dots
        document.getElementById('dot-val').textContent=s;//value received shown in span
    }
    for(var j=dotPos;j<30;j++) dots[j].style.visibility='hidden';//hide remaining dots
}
```

So if the value received is 25 in one second, 17 dots will be shown.. if in the next second the value received is 15, 10 dots will be shown, the rest will be hidden. Is there a better way of writing the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, move the `'dot-val'` setting out of the `for` loop (You're assigning the same value to it in each iteration of the `for` loop).
Also, you can change the display states in 1 loop, saving a `for`:

```
function updateImages(s) {
    var x = Math.round(s);
    var dotPos = x/1.5;
    for(var i=0;i<30;i++) {
        if(i < dotPos){
            dots[i].style.display='inline-block'; // Assuming they're inline-block elements.
        }else{
            dots[i].style.display='none';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('dot-val').textContent=s;//value received shown in span
}
```

Now, if you really want to trim your code, skip the temp `x` var, and use a [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#JavaScript):

```
function updateImages(s) {
    var dotPos = Math.round(s)/1.5;
    for(var i=0;i<30;i++) {
        dots[i].style.display = (i < dotPos)? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('dot-val').textContent = s;//value received shown in span
}
```

Comment: Its an img, so I used visibility attribute rather than display attribute. Is there an advantage of using display over visibility? 

By the way, the code is really fast as one loop is avoided! You should know that you are awesome.

Comment: I prefer using display, because usually, we don't need hidden elements to be considered in the positioning of other elements. Here's a nice explanation of the differences: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/visibility-vs-display/ By the way, thanks! :D Your reputation at the moment is "Not found" ;-)